# Gradient "climbing a mountain"

Tags: calculus

For the function:

$$f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^3$$

if we take the gradient $\nabla f$ we get $(-2x,{-2y^2})$ so for every positive point in the plane we will get a vector pointing downward? so if we look at the function as a "mountain" and we want to go up in the steepest path, we just take the direction $(2x,{2y^2})$?

Comment: In what sense is a vector with negative entries pointing "downwards"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think vector $(-x, -2y^2)$ looks downward? It's a vector on a plane, it's flat. However, it shows you the direction (still on a plane), where the function grows. There is nothing “downwardy” about the minus signs before $x$ and $y$ components

Comment: I see, so i am at a point a and I am going in the direction of the gradient, I will go down the mountain or up the mountain where the slope is the steepest?

Comment: Up the mountain

Comment: Why it is up the mountain and not down? as we said the gradient is in the XY plane not the Z axis

Comment: @newhere: I think you're confusing the *direction* of greatest increase (a vector) with the actual rate of increase (a scalar).  The latter is a directional derivative, while the former is a direction.  The gradient $\nabla f$ points in the direction of greatest increase, but its norm $|\nabla f|$ is that rate of increase.

Comment: @newhere: The gradient tells you in which direction to go **on the map** so that you go as quickly upwards as possible **in the terrain**.

Comment: @HansLundmark and if I want the same, just not upwards, rather downwards?

Comment: @newhere: Just go in the opposite direction, $-\nabla f$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the gradient vector itself denotes the direction you have to move in the input-plane (x-y) to get maximum height rise. So, that vector is given in cartesian coordinates as:
$$ \nabla F = \frac{ \partial F}{\partial x} \vec{i} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \vec{j}$$